# Unknown property 'CustomWrapperClass.Course__c'

Tags: apex

```
<apex:page controller="Customcontroller" sidebar="false" setup="false" showHeader="false" >
<apex:sectionHeader title="Wrapper" subtitle="Training Wrapper"/>
<apex:form >
<apex:pageBlock title="custom Wrapper Block">
<apex:pageblockTable value ="{!lstwrap}" var ="war">
<apex:column value="{!war.Name}"/>
<apex:column value="{!war.Course__c}"/>
<apex:column value="{!war.First_Name__c}"/>
<apex:column value="{!war.Last_Name__c}"/>
<apex:column value="{!war.Education__c}"/>

</apex:pageblockTable>

</apex:pageBlock>


</apex:form>

</apex:page>
```

```
public class Customcontroller {

public list<CustomWrapperClass> lstwrap{get;set;}
public void getrecords()
{
lstwrap = new list<CustomWrapperClass>();
list<Training_Deal__c> lstTrainingdeal = [select Name,Course__c from Training_Deal__c];
for(Training_Deal__c td : lstTrainingdeal)
{
CustomWrapperClass cwrap = new CustomWrapperClass(td);
lstwrap.add(cwrap);
}
list<Train__c> lstTrainer = [select First_Name__c,Last_Name__c,Education__c from Train__c];
for(Train__c t : lstTrainer)
{
CustomWrapperClass cwrap = new CustomWrapperClass(t);
lstwrap.add(cwrap);

}


}
}
```

```
public class CustomWrapperClass {
    
    public string Name{get;set;}
    public string Course{get;set;}
    public string FirstName{get;set;}
    Public string LastName{get;set;}
    public string Education{get;set;}
    
    public CustomWrapperClass(Training_Deal__c td)
    {
        
        Name = td.Name;
        Course = td.Course__c;
    }
    
    public CustomWrapperClass(Train__c t)
    {
        
        FirstName = t.First_Name__c;
        LastName = t.Last_Name__c;
        Education = t.Education__c;
    }
    
    

}
```

> Error:  Unknown property 'CustomWrapperClass.Course__c'

Comment: Please update your post with a description of the problem you are facing, what you have tried, where you are stuck. Dumping code with error messages  should be avoided. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The wrapper properties in VF mark-up do not match the actual properties in the apex class.
It should be like this :

```
<apex:column value="{!war.Name}"/>
<apex:column value="{!war.Course}"/>
<apex:column value="{!war.FirstName}"/>
<apex:column value="{!war.LastName}"/>
<apex:column value="{!war.Education}"/>
```

Comment: Thank you code is working with out any errors . but i am not able to get any out put after runnnig

Comment: Is there data in those custom objects?